# SpringMVC apache tomcat 7.0 java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.apache.catalina.deploy.WebXml addFilter

Tags: java, spring, apache, tomcat7

I work with Spring MVC,  the server Apache Tomcat 7.0.47 and java 1.6

When I start the server, I get the following errors

```
INFO: JSR 356 WebSocket (Java WebSocket 1.0) support is not available when running on Java 6. To suppress this message, run Tomcat on Java 7, remove the WebSocket JARs from $CATALINA_HOME/lib or add the WebSocketJARs to the tomcat.util.scan.DefaultJarScanner.jarsToSkip properhttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/askty in $CATALINA_BASE/conf/catalina.properties. Note that the deprecated Tomcat 7 WebSocket API will be available. 
21-jul-2017 7:35:56 org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(D:\eusurveyadaptado\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\eusurvey\WEB-INF\lib\el-api-2.2.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/el/Expression.class
21-jul-2017 7:35:56 org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(D:\eusurveyadaptado\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\eusurvey\WEB-INF\lib\servlet-api-2.5.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
21-jul-2017 7:35:56 org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(D:\eusurveyadaptado\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\eusurvey\WEB-INF\lib\tomcat-el-api-7.0.47.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/el/Expression.class
21-jul-2017 7:35:56 org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(D:\eusurveyadaptado\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\eusurvey\WEB-INF\lib\tomcat-embed-core-7.0.47.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
21-jul-2017 7:35:56 org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(D:\eusurveyadaptado\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\eusurvey\WEB-INF\lib\tomcat-servlet-api-7.0.47.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
21-jul-2017 7:35:56 org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester endElement
GRAVE: End event threw exception
**java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.apache.catalina.deploy.WebXml addFilter**
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.IntrospectionUtils.callMethod1(IntrospectionUtils.java:855)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetNextRule.end(SetNextRule.java:201)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.endElement(Digester.java:1051)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:601)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1782)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2939)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:648)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:511)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:808)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:737)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:119)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1205)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:522)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1537)
```

Where is the method addFilter?

I also can see the info messages:

```
INFO: JSR 356 WebSocket (Java WebSocket 1.0) support is not available when running on Java 6. To suppress this message, run Tomcat on Java 7, remove the WebSocket JARs from $CATALINA_HOME/lib or add the WebSocketJARs to the tomcat.util.scan.DefaultJarScanner.jarsToSkip property in $CATALINA_BASE/conf/catalina.properties. Note that the deprecated Tomcat 7 WebSocket API will be available. 
21-jul-2017 7:35:56 org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(D:\eusurveyadaptado\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\eusurvey\WEB-INF\lib\el-api-2.2.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/el/Expression.class
21-jul-2017 7:35:56 org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(D:\eusurveyadaptado\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\eusurvey\WEB-INF\lib\servlet-api-2.5.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
21-jul-2017 7:35:56 org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(D:\eusurveyadaptado\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\eusurvey\WEB-INF\lib\tomcat-el-api-7.0.47.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/el/Expression.class
21-jul-2017 7:35:56 org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(D:\eusurveyadaptado\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\eusurvey\WEB-INF\lib\tomcat-embed-core-7.0.47.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
21-jul-2017 7:35:56 org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(D:\eusurveyadaptado\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\eusurvey\WEB-INF\lib\tomcat-servlet-api-7.0.47.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
```

Do I have to fix these messages?

Comment: check your deployment assembly..you should not have `catelina.jar` in  **WEB-INF\lib\**  as they are provided by tomcat itself..you should remove it if it is present and restart the server

Answer (score 0):

Remove catalina.jar from your war WEB-INF/lib directory.

Sagar Kadu is correct, your eusurvey assembler should not have bundled it into your war.

If you are producing the war from maven also see [java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.apache.catalina.deploy.WebXml addServlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17487255/java-lang-nosuchmethodexception-org-apache-catalina-deploy-webxml-addservlet)